# I want combine text of two column in other column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to get the text of two cell in one cell with parenthesis on one cell.

```
| 1 | 20 | (1) 20 |
|:-:|:--:|--------|
```

I tried doing =CONCATENATE(A1,B1) but this is giving me 120

Comment: `C1="("&A1&") "&B1`

Comment: @Akina Thanks it is working.